# For Loop in R, all in 1 command

Tags: r

I created this random time series:

```
MM=1584
Z0<-rnorm(MM,8,1.0)#;ts.plot(Z0) 

s_1=1.50; p_1=121; p_2=240
s_2=1.25; p_3=361; p_4=480
s_3=1.10; p_5=601; p_6=720
s_4=1.50; p_7=960; p_8=1020
s_5=1.25; p_9=1140; p_10=1320
s_6=1.50; p_11=1369; p_12=1440

a=(Z0[1:p_1-1])
b=(s_1+Z0[p_1:p_2])
c=(Z0[(p_2+1):(p_3-1)])
d=(s_2+Z0[p_3:p_4])
e=(Z0[(p_4+1):(p_5-1)])
f=(s_2+Z0[p_5:p_6])
g=(Z0[(p_6+1):(p_7-1)])
h=(s_3+Z0[p_7:p_8])
i=(Z0[(p_8+1):(p_9-1)])
l=(s_4+Z0[p_9:p_10])
m=(Z0[(p_10+1):(p_11-1)])
n=(s_5+Z0[p_11:p_12])
o=Z0[(p_12+1):MM]


Z=c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,l,m,n,o);ts.plot(Z)
abline(v=p_1,col="red");abline(v=p_2,col="red");abline(v=p_3,col="red")
abline(v=p_4,col="red");abline(v=p_5,col="red");abline(v=p_6,col="red")
abline(v=p_7,col="red");abline(v=p_8,col="red");abline(v=p_9,col="red")
abline(v=p_10,col="red");abline(v=p_11,col="red");abline(v=p_12,col="red")

Zm=as.data.frame(Z)
write.csv2(Zm, file="C:/Users/Luca/Dekstop/Zm/Zm1.csv")
```

I would like to repeat these commands to create 100 series and to save these with write.cs2(...Zm"...".csv).

I don't want to change the file names and repeat the commands all manually.
I searched something useful in other questions but I didn't find it.

The loop has to change only the name of data frame (Zm) and the file names, for each loop.

I'm looking to repeat 100 times the creation of Z0 (Z01, Z02, Z03 ... Z0100) , then Z (Z1, Z2, ... Z100) so Zm (Zm1, Zm2, Zm3... Zm100) and save them in the folder with new file names (folder/Zm1, Zm2, Zm3 etc...) all in 1 command with a loop.

Comment: Just add the index of the current iteration to the name?

Comment: Are you looking to create a function taking an output name as parameter ?

Comment: 'm looking for to repeat 100 times the creation of Z0 (Z01, Z02, Z03 ... Z0100) , then Z (Z1, Z2, ... Z100) so Zm (Zm1, Zm2, Zm3... Zm100) and safe them in the folder with new name files  (folder/Zm1, Zm2, Zm3 etc...) all in 1 comand with a loop.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but using rep.int and the fact that the adjustments can be treated as zero where they don't apply, we can refactor the generation of Z as `rnorm(1584, 8, 1.0) + rep.int(c(0, 1.5, 0, 1.25, 0, 1.25, 0, 1.1, 0, 1.5, 0, 1.25, 0),  c(120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 239, 61, 119, 181, 48, 72, 144))`; which is slightly less prone to copy/paste errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to change the name of the data frames, but dynamically changing the name of the file is straightforward.

```
for (i in 1:100) { ... write.csv2(Zm, file=paste("C:/Users/Luca/Dekstop/Zm/Zm", i, ".csv", sep = "")) }
```

If you want to keep the created data frames, why not just simply use a list?

Comment: tho_mi, your comand in perfect, but how can I apply the loop also to all commands? from Z0 to Zm. Becuase I have to create 100 different random series.

Comment: What do you want to do with these data frames?